# Scrapy shell can't crawl information while xpath works in Chrome console

Tags: xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm working on a project to collect the university's professors contact information. (So it is not malicious.)
The professor page is dynamic. I find out the request via Chrome network. However, scrapy xpath doesn't work in scrapy shell while it works on the browser. I even tried to add headers.
[scrapy shell result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHcym.png)

[Chrome console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lImq.png)

```
import scrapy
from universities.items import UniversitiesItem


class UniversityOfHouston(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'University_of_Houston'
    allowed_domains = ['uh.edu']
    start_urls = ['http://www.uh.edu/directory/']

    def __init__(self):
        self.lastName = ''

    def parse(self, response):
        self.lastName = 'An'
        query = "http://www.uh.edu/directory/proxy.php?q=" + self.lastName + \
                "&submit=Search&limit=250&loc=HR730&pos=faculty%7Cstaff&faculty=faculty&staff=staff&student=student"

        yield scrapy.Request(query, callback=self.parse_staff)

    def parse_staff(self, response):
        results = response.xpath('//dt/a/@href').extract()
        for result in results:
            query = 'http://www.uh.edu/directory/' + result
            yield scrapy.Request(query, callback=self.parse_item)

    def parse_item(self, response):

        item = UniversitiesItem()

        item['full_name'] = response.xpath('//h2[@class="single_title"]/text()').extract_first()
        item['university'] = 'University of Houston'
        item['discipline'] = response.xpath('//td/a[@class="org"]/text()').extract_first()
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//tr/td[@class="title"]/text()')
        item['email'] = response.xpath('//td/a[@title="email address"]/text()').extract_first()[7:]
        item['phone'] = response.xpath('//td[@class="tel"]/a/text()').extract_first()

        yield item
```

Test version:

```
import scrapy
from universities.items import UniversitiesItem


class UniversityOfHouston(scrapy.Spider):
    #name = 'University_of_Houston'
    name = 'uh2'
    allowed_domains = ['uh.edu']
    start_urls = ['http://www.uh.edu/directory/']

    def __init__(self):
        self.last_name = ''

    def parse(self, response):
        with open('kw.txt') as file_object:
            last_names = file_object.readlines()

        for ln in ['Lee', 'Zhao']:
            self.last_name = ln.strip()
            print('-----------------------------------------------------')
            print("scraping last name: ", self.last_name)
            query = "http://www.uh.edu/directory/proxy.php?q=" + self.last_name + \
                    "&submit=Search&limit=250&loc=HR730&pos=faculty%7Cstaff&faculty=faculty&staff=staff&student=student"

            yield scrapy.Request(query, callback=self.parse_staff)

    def parse_staff(self, response):
        results = response.xpath('//dt/a/@href').extract()
        for result in results:
            query_proxy = 'http://www.uh.edu/directory/' + result.replace("index.php", "proxy.php")
            yield scrapy.Request(query_proxy, callback=self.parse_item)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        full_name = response.xpath('//h2[@class="single_title"]/text()').extract_first()
        if full_name:
            if self.last_name in full_name.split():
                item = UniversitiesItem()
                item['fullname'] = full_name
                # last_name = full_name.split()[-1]
                # item['lastname'] = last_name
                # item['firstname'] = full_name[:-len(last_name)].strip()
                item['university'] = 'University of Houston'
                try:
                    item['department'] = response.xpath('//td/a[@class="org"]/text()').extract_first()
                    item['title'] = response.xpath('//tr/td[@class="title"]/text()').extract_first()
                    item['email'] = response.xpath('//td/a[@title="email address"]/text()').extract_first()
                    item['phone'] = response.xpath('//td[@class="tel"]/a/text()').extract_first()
                except ValueError:
                    pass

                yield item
```

Comment: Open firefox go to `about:config` search `javascript.enabled` and set it to false. Then open your page in firefox. If you don't see the data you want then the page use javascript script and just scrapy won't do. You need to us Scrapy+Splash combination or you need to use Scrapy+Selenium

Comment: I don't have firefox, but I'll try. I used Scrapy+Selenium before. But it returns error: selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException. I set delay to 20s it still doesn't work. I'm considering to use Scrapy+Phantomjs.

Comment: Post your code in question

Comment: @Tarun Lalwani Posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the data is fetched using AJAX call on the web page. And the data is not available when you fetch the main page

[image: AJAX Call]

Change your `parse_staff` function to below and it should work

```
def parse_staff(self, response):
    results = response.xpath('//dt/a/@href').extract()
    for result in results:
        query = 'http://www.uh.edu/directory/' + result
        query_proxy = "https://ssl.uh.edu/directory/" + result.replace("index.php", "proxy.php")
        yield response.follow(query_proxy, callback=self.parse_item)
```

Comment: Wow, it works. But shouldn't query_proxy start with [http://www.uh.edu/directory](http://www.uh.edu/directory) ? Where did you find [https://ssl](https://ssl) ?

Comment: In chrome developer tools, network tab. You should always check what the page is doing before scraping

Comment: Yes, [http://www.uh.edu/directory](http://www.uh.edu/directory) that's what I saw in network tab.

Comment: The page then makes call to this URL, so we can skip going to this page and directly go to the one which fetches us the data

Comment: Here is another problem. My script can only save one item in the result (I tried to save it into a csv file). Could you figure it out why? I just posted a test version.

Comment: I mean there are 2 key words in the loop, which are "Lee" and "Zhao". But only "Zhao" is being saved.