# xpath results different from scrapy and browser console

Tags: selenium, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm using selenium and PhantomJS to collect the professors' contact information (not in malicious purpose) from the university [web page](http://iupuijags.com/staff.aspx)

For testing purpose, let's say kw.txt is a file contains only two last names looks like

max

lee

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver

from universities.items import UniversitiesItem

class iupui(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'iupui'
    allowed_domains = ['iupui.com']
    start_urls = ['http://iupuijags.com/staff.aspx']

    def __init__(self):
        self.last_name = ''

    def parse(self, response):
        with open('kw.txt') as file_object:
            last_names = file_object.readlines()

        for ln in last_names:
            #driver = webdriver.PhantomJS("C:\\Users\yashi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\Scripts\phantomjs.exe")
            driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\yashi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\chromedriver.exe')
            driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
            driver.get('http://iupuijags.com/staff.aspx')

            kw_search = driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_cplhMainContent_txtSearch')
            search = driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_cplhMainContent_btnSearch')

            self.last_name = ln.strip()
            kw_search.send_keys(self.last_name)
            search.click()

            item = UniversitiesItem()
            results = response.xpath('//table[@class="default_dgrd staff_dgrd"]//tr[contains(@class,"default_dgrd_item '
                                    'staff_dgrd_item") or contains(@class, "default_dgrd_alt staff_dgrd_alt")]')
            for result in results:
                full_name = result.xpath('./td[@class="staff_dgrd_fullname"]/a/text()').extract_first()
                print(full_name)
                if self.last_name in full_name.split():
                    item['full_name'] = full_name
                    email = result.xpath('./td[@class="staff_dgrd_staff_email"]/a/href').extract_first()
                    if email is not None:
                        item['email'] = email[7:]
                    else:
                        item['email'] = ''
                    item['phone'] = result.xpath('./td[@class="staff_dgrd_staff_phone"]/text()').extract_first()
                yield item
            driver.close()
```

However, the result always give me a bunch of names looks like

```
2017-09-12 15:27:13 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
Dr. Roderick Perry
2017-09-12 15:27:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://iupuijags.com/staff.aspx>
{}
Gail Barksdale
2017-09-12 15:27:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://iupuijags.com/staff.aspx>
{}
John Rasmussen
2017-09-12 15:27:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://iupuijags.com/staff.aspx>
{}
Jared Chasey
2017-09-12 15:27:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://iupuijags.com/staff.aspx>
{}
Denise O'Grady
2017-09-12 15:27:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://iupuijags.com/staff.aspx>
{}
Ed Holdaway
2017-09-12 15:27:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://iupuijags.com/staff.aspx>
{}
```

The lenght of the result is always the same on each iteration.

This is how it looks like in the console when I put the xpath in it:
[console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5DUz.png)

I really can't figure it out what's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So few issues as such.

- You are not using the response from your selenium code. You are
  browsing the page and then doing nothing from the source of the page.
- Next you are yielding item even when a match is not found and hence
  blank items.
- Also you are create the item outside loop when it should be inside
- The comparisons you are doing are case sensitive. So you check for
  `max` but the results has `Max` and you ignore the match.
- You also have a missing `@` in href for email.

Below is a fixed version

```
class iupui(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'iupui'
    allowed_domains = ['iupui.com']
    start_urls = ['http://iupuijags.com/staff.aspx']

    # def __init__(self):
    #     self.last_name = ''

    def parse(self, response):
        # with open('kw.txt') as file_object:
        #     last_names = file_object.readlines()
        last_names = ["max"]
        for ln in last_names:
            #driver = webdriver.PhantomJS("C:\\Users\yashi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\Scripts\phantomjs.exe")
            driver = webdriver.Chrome()
            driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
            driver.get('http://iupuijags.com/staff.aspx')

            kw_search = driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_cplhMainContent_txtSearch')
            search = driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_cplhMainContent_btnSearch')

            self.last_name = ln.strip()
            kw_search.send_keys(self.last_name)
            search.click()

            res = response.replace(body=driver.page_source)


            results = res.xpath('//table[@class="default_dgrd staff_dgrd"]//tr[contains(@class,"default_dgrd_item '
                                    'staff_dgrd_item") or contains(@class, "default_dgrd_alt staff_dgrd_alt")]')
            for result in results:
                full_name = result.xpath('./td[@class="staff_dgrd_fullname"]/a/text()').extract_first()
                print(full_name)
                if self.last_name.lower() in full_name.lower().split():
                    item = UniversitiesItem()

                    item['full_name'] = full_name
                    email = result.xpath('./td[@class="staff_dgrd_staff_email"]/a/@href').extract_first()
                    if email is not None:
                        item['email'] = email[7:]
                    else:
                        item['email'] = ''
                    item['phone'] = result.xpath('./td[@class="staff_dgrd_staff_phone"]/text()').extract_first()
                    yield item
            driver.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It looks good though I don't have a machine to test it. res = response.replace(body=driver.page_source) . I think this is the key problem. And 'max' is just my mistake. It should be 'Max' in the keyword.txt. I also keep opening and closing the browser. That was very stupid. But now I think I can put it out of the loop until the entire crawling job done.

Comment: It works! Thank you! Would you like to look at another similar question I asked? I think I should replace response with something else as well. 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46125667/scrapy-shell-cant-crawl-information-while-xpath-works-in-chrome-console?noredirect=1#comment79217663_46125667